# How do I record the process execution time in nanoseconds using C on a linux operating system using clock_getttime()?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to record the time of execution for a process using C while on a linux operating system, I believe it is CentOs, it is a school server and I don't know the hardware specs. The program I am trying to run looks in a directory and runs all the jobs in the directory that follow the pattern Job1, Job2 etc. I am running these files which are executable files by using the system call system() fucntion with an absolute path to each executable file as a parameter (i.e system(jobpath);).

I am also trying to time how long it takes to run the job that I just called by calling clock_gettime() before and after the system(jobpath) call. I have two timespec variables which I am passing to the two different calls to clock_gettime() called start and end. I am also using the CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID clock ID, and the code for that part looks something like this:

```
           clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, start);
           system(jobpath)//is a path to a job that takes 2-3 seconds in real time to finish
           clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, end);
```

The only problem is that when I go to print out the tv_nsec variable for end, I get a zero value when it obviously does not take 0 nanoseconds to run the jobs. Can anyone tell me why the function will record zero nanoseconds for something that obviously takes more time than that, and what I can possibly do to get real results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command executed by `system` will be run in another process so it won't add any cpu time to the current process.

Edit: 
As to your second question, you could use `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` to time the actual elapsed time of the `system` call, but that won't tell you the cpu elapsed time of the `system` call.  I'm not sure if the actual elapsed time is good enough for you.

Comment: Do you know of any way that I can record that process's execution time?

Comment: Actual elapsed time should work if there is no other way to record the cpu time then I'm fine with it, thank you.

Comment: You might want to read about `wait3` or `getrusage`, but in order to use `wait3`, you would need to fork and exec instead of using `system`.